# How would I make background of slideshow more opaque

Tags: html, css

I kinda want to make the black background a little transparent but unfortunately its also making the image within the slide transparent as well.

**Code:**

```
#slideshow {
    float:left;
    width: 810px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;  
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#slideshow img {
    margin: 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Saurabh that will set the image's opacity too, as mentioned by Gorvilla in his/her question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RGBA()` to set a background color with opacity.

Example:

```
#div {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

This will make your background black with 40% opacity.

Answer (score 0):

The background color can have [alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) which is `RGBA` the last value is the alpha and should be between 0 and 1, where 0 is invisible and 1 is opaque. The first 3 values are the same as if you were using `RGB` (as you are anyway)

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 0 0, radial-gradient(black 15%, transparent 16%) 8px 8px, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 0 1px, radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 15%, transparent 20%) 8px 9px;
  background-color: #282828;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
}
#slideshow {
  float: left;
  width: 810px;
  height: 360px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
#slideshow img {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/ujIagYPIwiD4ifRt8MxAXqqsQ3BHqc8wv5BVwpoC1wiWqeRyhYGqQr1vKEJcsFchNcfM=w300" />
</div>
```

I gave the body a background so you could see it was working. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: This is duplicate to my answer, Stackoverflow allows you to edit/suggest an answer to add content.